# Windows Registry set by System Administrator - Overwrite

Tags: registry, administrator, regedit, system-administration

At my job, I received a laptop which allows me to install programs and edit the **Windows Registry** using *Elevated Rights*. However, periodically, my **System Administrator** seems to revert certain keys in the **Registry** to their will. This probably goes via the network.

In particular, I wish to permanently delete `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-90921563-173218475-988572150-123110\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlacklist` which blocks me from using *Chrome Extensions*. I can delete it and use *Chrome* as I like for a while, but it goes back to being blocked after some time.

Does anyone know a trick to either block my **Administrator** from editing my **Registry** or to permanently delete this one key? Or otherwise to make *Chrome* ignore the **Registry**?

Comment: You are asking for a hack. This might cost you your job. My suggestion, even if you find a way to do this, don't do. It's your job/reputation vs some extensions of Chrome.

Comment: Mh, fair point. Any idea on how to make Chrome bypass the Registry then?

Comment: Ummm...then again it's a hack. For that, you have to hook the browser and change the registry query code or change the value returned after the browser has read the registry. Believe me, it's messy. There is no clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get a "not a programming question" reprimand ;_)

One brute approach to the problem is to export that "hive" from within regedit to, say, your desktop.  So you have a chrome.reg file sitting on there.  After logging in (which is probably when group policy is being applied), double click chrome.reg and your settings will be reapplied.  You may even be able to put that file in the startup folder, and windows will do it for you.  Or find another way to make windows run it later ("start chrome.reg"?)

Comment: Good tip, unfortunately, I need Elevated Rights to run the .reg, meaning that I need to put in a large amount of effort every single time I want to overwrite the group policy. Effort I don't have...

Comment: Setup a batch file on the desktop with "reg import chrome.reg".  Right click and "Run as Administrator". Though maybe you have to jump through more hoops to get your elevated rights?  I agree with the comments about not subverting your IT policy, but if you are granted these elevated rights, it's presumably part of the deal.  I've been in the same situation - granted local admin, but if it breaks support consists of re-imaging :-)